# Why were no interferometers launched on weather satellites between the '69-'72 IRIS-D and the 2002-onward AIRS?

Tags: earth-observation, weather-satellites

As early as the late 1960s / early 1970s, [Nimbus-3](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/satellites/view/317) carried [Iris-B](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/228) and [Nimbus-4](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/satellites/view/318) carried [Iris-D](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/229), both infrared spectroradiometers with a moderate spectral resolution.  Subsequently, I believe it was not until [AIRS](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/16) flew on [EOS-Aqua](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/satellites/view/79) (launch 2002), and subsequently [IASI](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/207) on [EPS](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/satelliteprogrammes/view/44) and [CrIS](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/93) on [SNPP](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/satelliteprogrammes/view/113) and on [JPSS](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/satelliteprogrammes/view/87), that spectrometers were flown on (semi-)operational weather satellites.  Why is this so?  Were IRIS-B and IRIS-D considered unsuccessful, prohibitively expensive, or did agencies simply prioritise on other things?

**EDIT 2019-03-20**: There was actually one other hyperspectral interferometer: The [Spectrometer Interferometer](https://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/1014) was [flown on several Meteor satellites](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0094576580900156?via%3Dihub).  The instrument was built by the *Academy of Sciences of German Democratic Republic (GDR), in collaboration with the former Soviet Hydrometeorological Service (HYDROMET) and the former Meteorological Service of GDR (Spänkuch 1980)* and flew in the late 1970s / early 1980s.